# Sass --watch not compiling

Tags: sass

I am running Sass from terminal like this:

```
sass --watch --style expanded css:css/compiled
```

I have these files:

- compiled.scss
- _style.scss
- _forms.scss

compiled.scss @imports the other two files

When I modify _style.scss and save it I get

> Change detected to [path to file]
>
> overwrite css/compiled/main.css

but modifying _forms.scss I get

> Change detected to [path to file]

But no overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

You have not @imported '_forms.scss' properly into 'compiled.scss'